# Display Announcement list from sub site

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have SharePoint Server 2010 Standard and am trying to put a short announcement List on my home site which is from a sub sub site. I tried creating a Content Query Web Part, selected the source as "Show items from the following list:" and entered the address of the announcement list. In "Content Type" I selected "List Content Types" and "Announcement".
Under Advanced I added the URL of the Announcement List in the Title URL field.

It works, but I am not getting the new image icon not the link to "Add new announcement".
How can I get these two to appear?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define your own template for XSL and define what is "new" (eg. not older than a day) and based on this display image next to the title.
You can as well add the buttom "Add new item" to this template or just add content web part under your cqwp.